# PHP & MySQL - How to count the number of times data was entered for a specific user?

Tags: php, mysql, tag-cloud

Let's say I want to display the tags related to `users_question_id` **1** and I want to count the number of times that tag was entered for that question by 1 each time it was entered in-order to display the tags that where entered more bigger.

How would I do this using MySQL and PHP I have created two tables called `questions_tags` and `tags`.

Here is the MySQL tables layout

```
Table questions_tags

id  tag_id  users_questions_id
46  46      1
47  47      29
48  48      1
49  49      11
50  50      1
51  51      1
52  52      345
53  53      1
54  54      1
55  55      100
56  56      1
57  57      1
58  58      1
59  59      1
60  60      1
```

And here is the second table.

```
Table tags

id  tag
46  a
47  x
48  a
49  r
50  a
51  a
52  k
53  a
54  a
55  q
56  b
57  c
58  d
59  d
60  z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT t.tag,
          COUNT(q.tag_id) 'num'
     FROM QUESTIONS_TAGS q
     JOIN TAGS t ON t.id = q.tag_id
    WHERE q.users_questions_id = 1
 GROUP BY t.tag
 ORDER BY num DESC
```

Comment: I assume the t and q are abbr. :) I'll try this in a bit I got something to do. thanks

Comment: Aliases, not abbreviations :)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work maybe I read your aliases wrong :) I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am out of time, but check out SQL for the `count()` function.

Comment: That sucks because i dont't no where to begin. oh well

Comment: @SlaPtHiS Seriously? Typing SQL count() in Google was too hard?